# TFLearn produces same results on every prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

My network produces the same output for every prediction. I have about 49,000 data samples in a pandas data frame.
How can I fix this?

```
# Input data X.as_matrix() => 8 dimensional array  
# One example: [1.50000000e+00,3.00000000e+00,6.00000000e+00,2.40000000e+01,9.50000000e+01,3.00000000e+03,5.00000000e+00,1.50000000e+00]  
import tensorflow as tf  
import tflearn  

with tf.Graph().as_default():  
    net = tflearn.input_data([None, 8])  

    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 20, activation='softmax',weights_init='normal',regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.001)   
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 3, activation='softmax',weights_init='normal')  
    sgd = tflearn.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)  
    net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer=sgd,loss='categorical_crossentropy')  
    model = tflearn.DNN(net)  
    model.fit(X.as_matrix(), Y, show_metric=True, batch_size=10, n_epoch=2, snapshot_epoch=False)  
print(model.predict([X.as_matrix()[1]]))  
print(model.predict([X.as_matrix()[2]]))  
print(model.predict([X.as_matrix()[3]]))    

Result:  
[0.6711940169334412,0.24268993735313416,0.08611597120761871]  
[0.6711940169334412,0.24268993735313416,0.08611597120761871]  
[0.6711940169334412,0.24268993735313416,0.08611597120761871]  

Actual:  
[ 0,  1,  0]  
[ 1,  0,  0]  
[ 0,  0,  1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sigmoid or relu instead of softmax. I got better predictions with those 2. Maybe you want to use sigmoid for the first and relu for the second layer. Just play with them and combine them, so that you have better predictions. Also try other loss functions.